# Is it possible to run code when the REMOVE button is clicked from a managed file?

Tags: forms, files

I have a managed_file field on a custom form when I need to run some code if the REMOVE button is clicked after uploading a file.

PURPOSE:

When a user uploads a file to the managed_file field on the custom field a second managed file is created for processing purposes. If the user cancels by clicking the REMOVE file button I need to run code to also remove the secondary file that I created programmatically.

Comment: Is the remove button part of a Drupal form? If so, you can just use `hook_form_alter()` to attach a submit handler to the remove button, and then run your custom code in the submit handler.

Comment: You could always leave the status of the second managed file as `0`, and only update to `1` on successful form submission. The orphaned second file would then be cleared up on cron in x hours (default 6 I think)